# Cannot create a database table named 'user' in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, identifier, reserved-words

It seems PostgreSQL does not allow to create a database table named 'user'. But MySQL will allow to create such a table.

Is that because it is a key word? But Hibernate cannot identify any issue (even if we set the PostgreSQLDialect).

Comment: Yes, user is a reserved keyword. Just don't use it as a table name. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: You can create a table named 'user' on postgreSQL. But i advice you to avoid using table/column/variables ...  names using token keywords

Comment: So sorry this is not a duplicate question. Question is about  postgresql not about some thing with MySql. Thanks.

Comment: Similar: [*Using `type` as database column name*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36160240/642706)

Answer (score 230, accepted):

`user` is a reserved word and it's usually not a good idea use reserved words for identifiers (tables, columns).

If you insist on doing that you have to put the table name in double quotes:

```
create table "user" (...);
```

But then you **always** need to use double quotes when referencing the table. Additionally the table name is then case-sensitive. `"user"` is a different table name than `"User"`.

If you want to save yourself a lot of trouble use a different name. `users`, `user_account`, ...

More details on quoted identifiers can be found in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an answer in a Hibernate-based project, as the topicstarter mentioned =) The actual problem here is Hibernate's failure to do that sort of escaping automatically. Despite being told the proper dialect! So the proper answer should say describe how to make in work in Hibernate, not in PSQL :(

Comment: @MaksimGumerov: the proper answer is: don't use names that require quoted identifiers - regardless of the obfuscation layer you are using.

Comment: Nope that's not the one :) You'll end up tying your code to specific database and its keywords (and this set is subject to changes). One actual solution is turn on escaping globally (did not try it myself though), another is rely on Hibernate dialect analyzers (but as we see, they don't always do their job in determining whether we need to escape something).

Comment: @MaksimGumerov the point is that you can't create the table named user because it is reserved by the database.

Comment: Sure I can - using quotes, for one. Maybe I should not but even that is arguable. What's more important is HOW do I create such a table, and the solution proposed here (one with quotation) will not help in Hibernate projects. And the initial question mentions Hibernate, so the answer actually does not answer it well enough IMO.

Comment: What's even more important (though non-constructive) is, JPA was supposed to let us not think about dialects when writing our entity classes, and here we are talking about how I cannot use a table name for Postgres that's completely valid for Mysql. Tada. (And that's despite the fact JPA could do necessary name escaping for us: it just fails to)

Comment: I would recommend not to use "user" (I mean in PostgreSQL) just like was mentioned, it is a reserved word, and when I used it (I mean with quotes), it caused many useless problems.

Comment: hours of frustration because of this. thank for the answer.

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"' [select generatedAlias0 from "user" as generatedAlias0]

Answer (score 29):

It is possible to specify tablename with JPA with next syntax:

```
@Table(name="\"user\"")
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Without that I was getting errors like `column user0_.id does not exist`

Comment: This one worked for me, is so weird that user is a reserved word since it is used as a table name for almost every application I have worked with during my entire career.

Answer (score 18):

## Trailing underscore `_`

The SQL standard *explicitly* promises to never use a trailing [underscore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore#Unicode) (U+005F LOW LINE) in any name, keyword, or reserved word. To see for yourself, search the spec for the word “underscore”.

So, to avoid conflicts with any of the **over a thousand keywords and reserved words** used by various database engines, I name all my database identifiers with a trailing underscore. (Yes, really, over a thousand keywords reserved — I counted them.)

Change this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user ( … ) ;
```

… to this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_ ( … ) ;
```

I do this as a habit for all database names: schemas, tables, columns, indexes, etc.

I rest a bit easier knowing I’ve eliminated an entire class of bugs and problems caused by naming collisions.

As an extra benefit, this practice makes quite clear in documentation, email, and such when referring to a programming language variable named `user` versus the database column `user_`. Anything with a trailing underscore is obviously from the database side.

Comment: That's a smart and easy move.

Comment: this is what real experience in the field looks like

Comment: How you name associative tables?

Answer (score 12):

We had this same issue time ago, and we just changed the table name from `user` to `app_user`. Due to the use of Hibernate/JPA. We thought it would be easier this way.
Hope this little fix will help someone else.

Comment: Did the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a table `user` in a schema other than `public`.
The example:

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;
CREATE TABLE my_schema.user(...);
```