# Don't get all users object in web application spring mvc + jpa + postgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I uses spring MVC, JPA, postgreSQL develop Web Application

Here is some codes:

File: user.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private DateTime birthDate;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean isActive;
    private String lastModifiedPerson;
    private DateTime createdDate;
    private DateTime lastModifiedDate;
    private int version;

    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    private Set<Entry> entrys = new HashSet<Entry>();
    private Set<EntryComment> comments = new HashSet<EntryComment>();



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Column(name="BIRTHDATE")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)
    public DateTime getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }
    public void setBirthDate(DateTime birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name="PHONE")
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name="ISACTIVE")
    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }
    public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }
    @Column(name="LAST_MODIFIED_BY")
    public String getLastModifiedPerson() {
        return lastModifiedPerson;
    }
    public void setLastModifiedPerson(String lastModifiedPerson) {
        this.lastModifiedPerson = lastModifiedPerson;
    }

    @Column(name="CREATE_DATE")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)
    public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Column(name="LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)
    public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }
    public void setLastModifiedDate(DateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getBirthDateString(){
        String birthDateString="";
        if(birthDate != null)
            birthDateString = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").print(birthDate);
        return birthDateString;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getLastModifiedDateString(){
        String birthDateString="";
        if(lastModifiedDate != null)
            birthDateString = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").print(lastModifiedDate);
        return birthDateString;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getCreateDateString(){
        String birthDateString="";
        if(createdDate != null)
            birthDateString = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").print(createdDate);
        return birthDateString;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID"))
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    public Set<Entry> getEntrys() {
        return entrys;
    }
    public void setEntrys(Set<Entry> entrys) {
        this.entrys = entrys;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<EntryComment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }
    public void setComments(Set<EntryComment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    @Version
    @Column(name="VERSION")
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "User - Id:" + id +", Name: "+ name +", Username: " + username +", CreatedDate: " + createdDate;  
    }
}
```

File: UserRepository.java

```
package com.software.booksocial.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.software.booksocial.domain.User;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

File:UserService.java

```
package com.software.booksocial.service;
import java.util.List;
import com.software.booksocial.domain.User;

public interface UserService {
     List<User> findAll();
     User findById(Long id);
     User save(User user);
}
```

File: UserServiceIml.java

```
package com.software.booksocial.service.jpa;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.software.booksocial.domain.User;
import com.software.booksocial.repository.UserRepository;
import com.software.booksocial.service.UserService;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

@Repository
@Transactional
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceIml implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> findAll(){
        return Lists.newArrayList(userRepository.findAll());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public User findById(Long id){
        return userRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user){
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    //@Autowired
    //public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository){
    //  this.userRepository = userRepository;
    //}
}
```

File:UserController.java

```
package com.software.booksocial.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.software.booksocial.domain.User;
import com.software.booksocial.service.UserService;

@RequestMapping("/users")
@Controller
public class UserController {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model uiModel){
        logger.info("Listing Users");

        List<User> users = userService.findAll();

        uiModel.addAttribute("users", users);

        logger.info("No. of users: " + users.size());

        return "users/list";
    }

}
```

And Database Struction in image link:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39630113/DBBookSocial.png

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39630113/Picture/DBUpdate.png

Main Error:

> Hibernate: select user0_.ID as ID1_8_, user0_.ISACTIVE as
>   ISACTIVE2_8_, user0_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS3_8_, user0_.BIRTHDATE as
>   BIRTHDAT4_8_, user0_.CREATE_DATE as CREATE_D5_8_, user0_.EMAIL as
>   EMAIL6_8_, user0_.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE as LAST_MOD7_8_,
>   user0_.LAST_MODIFIED_BY as LAST_MOD8_8_, user0_.NAME as NAME9_8_,
>   user0_.PASSWORD as PASSWOR10_8_, user0_.PHONE as PHONE11_8_,
>   user0_.USERNAME as USERNAM12_8_, user0_.VERSION as VERSION13_8_ from
>   USER user0_ WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -
>   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703 ERROR:
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column
>   user0_.id does not exist   Position: 8 Jan 27, 2015 4:37:45 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path
>   [/readersocial] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet] with root cause org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   column user0_.id does not exist   Position: 8

And Error Text:

> Hibernate: select user0_.ID as ID1_8_, user0_.ISACTIVE as
>   ISACTIVE2_8_, user0_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS3_8_, user0_.BIRTHDATE as
>   BIRTHDAT4_8_, user0_.CREATE_DATE as CREATE_D5_8_, user0_.EMAIL as
>   EMAIL6_8_, user0_.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE as LAST_MOD7_8_,
>   user0_.LAST_MODIFIED_BY as LAST_MOD8_8_, user0_.NAME as NAME9_8_,
>   user0_.PASSWORD as PASSWOR10_8_, user0_.PHONE as PHONE11_8_,
>   user0_.USERNAME as USERNAM12_8_, user0_.VERSION as VERSION13_8_ from
>   USER user0_ WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -
>   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703 ERROR:
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column
>   user0_.id does not exist   Position: 8 Jan 27, 2015 4:37:45 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path
>   [/readersocial] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet] with root cause org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   column user0_.id does not exist   Position: 8     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:304)     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:442)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:427)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.findAll(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.software.booksocial.service.jpa.UserServiceIml.findAll(UserServiceIml.java:25)
>     at
>   com.software.booksocial.controller.UserController.list(UserController.java:30)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1033)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Jan 27, 2015 5:00:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   reload INFO: Reloading Context with name [/readersocial] has started
>   Jan 27, 2015 5:00:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet' INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext -
>   Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet':
>   startup date [Tue Jan 27 16:37:28 ICT 2015]; parent: Root
>   WebApplicationContext Jan 27, 2015 5:00:48 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Closing Spring
>   root WebApplicationContext INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext -
>   Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jan 27 16:37:17
>   ICT 2015]; root of context hierarchy Jan 27, 2015 5:00:48 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
>   SEVERE: The web application [/readersocial] registered the JDBC driver
>   [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web
>   application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has
>   been forcibly unregistered. Jan 27, 2015 5:00:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath Jan 27, 2015
>   5:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root
>   WebApplicationContext: initialization started INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext -
>   Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jan 27
>   17:00:56 ICT 2015]; root of context hierarchy INFO :
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader -
>   Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml] INFO :
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader -
>   Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource
>   [datasource-tx-jpa.xml] INFO :
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
>   - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring WARN : org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence - HHH015016:
>   Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
>   [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
>   [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root
>   WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 13934 ms Jan 27,
>   2015 5:01:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet' INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet
>   'appServlet': initialization started INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext -
>   Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet':
>   startup date [Tue Jan 27 17:01:10 ICT 2015]; parent: Root
>   WebApplicationContext INFO :
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader -
>   Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] INFO :
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
>   - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
>   - Mapped "{[/users],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}"
>   onto public java.lang.String
>   com.software.booksocial.controller.UserController.list(org.springframework.ui.Model)
>   INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
>   - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}"
>   onto public java.lang.String
>   com.software.booksocial.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
>   INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
>   - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Tue Jan 27 17:01:10 ICT 2015];
>   parent: Root WebApplicationContext INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
>   - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Tue Jan 27 17:01:10 ICT 2015];
>   parent: Root WebApplicationContext INFO :
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping -
>   Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
>   INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
>   FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 1486 ms Jan
>   27, 2015 5:01:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
>   INFO: Reloading Context with name [/readersocial] is completed

I don't get all user from table USER from UserController using spring data jpa. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Try to execute this directly on your database: `select user0_.ID as ID1_8_, user0_.ISACTIVE as ISACTIVE2_8_, user0_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS3_8_, user0_.BIRTHDATE as BIRTHDAT4_8_, user0_.CREATE_DATE as CREATE_D5_8_, user0_.EMAIL as EMAIL6_8_, user0_.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE as LAST_MOD7_8_, user0_.LAST_MODIFIED_BY as LAST_MOD8_8_, user0_.NAME as NAME9_8_, user0_.PASSWORD as PASSWOR10_8_, user0_.PHONE as PHONE11_8_, user0_.USERNAME as USERNAM12_8_, user0_.VERSION as VERSION13_8_ from USER user0_`

Comment: Depending on the database it might be that your column names are case sensitive. You have `id` as the name but your code expects `ID`.

Comment: Without even looking on the whole question quick question from my side - do You have in Your mind that 'user' is a keyword?

Comment: Dear  @PredragMaric , thanks for helping. I had executed follow your instruction, And result is: ERROR:  column user0_.id does not exist
LINE 1: select user0_.ID as ID1_8_, user0_.ISACTIVE as ISACTIVE2_8_,...
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column user0_.id does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 8

Comment: I think @wojtek88 is wright, I've edited my answer.

Comment: To check weather it is a case-sensitivity issue, try executing on the database `select id from app_user` and `select ID from APP_USER` to see what happens

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`user` is a reserved keyword in Postgres (as you were told in the comments), so your best option is to rename the table to something else (like `APP_USER`) and change the entity mapping to `@Table(name = "APP_USER")`.

If you can't/don't wont to change table name, you would have to enclose the table name in double quotes wherever you use it, starting with `@Table(name = " \"USER\"")`, but if  I remember correctly this caused some bugs the last time I tried it, when you query other entities that are related to `User` (double quotes weren't applied in `join` statements, but that could be fixed by now).

Anyway, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256124/cannot-create-a-database-table-named-user-in-postgresql) for more info.

Comment: i have a column id in table user. Thanks for reply. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39630113/DBBookSocial.png

Comment: Try to execute this directly on your database `select user0_.ID as ID1_8_, user0_.ISACTIVE as ISACTIVE2_8_, user0_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS3_8_, user0_.BIRTHDATE as BIRTHDAT4_8_, user0_.CREATE_DATE as CREATE_D5_8_, user0_.EMAIL as EMAIL6_8_, user0_.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE as LAST_MOD7_8_, user0_.LAST_MODIFIED_BY as LAST_MOD8_8_, user0_.NAME as NAME9_8_, user0_.PASSWORD as PASSWOR10_8_, user0_.PHONE as PHONE11_8_, user0_.USERNAME as USERNAM12_8_, user0_.VERSION as VERSION13_8_ from USER user0_`

Answer (score 0):

The [bigserial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html) PostgreSQL type takes 8 bytes, while your Java id is an `int` primitive (32 bits = 4 bytes).

Change your id to:

```
private Long id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Using a wrapper is always better than using a primitive because Hibernate can easily differentiate between a transient and a detached [entity state](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/).

As for the IDENTIFIER generator, I think that only works because Hibernate assigns a single global sequence for serving all such IDENTIFIER generators. I suggest you switch to a [SEQUENCE generator](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/), possibly a [pooled-lo](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/) optimizer too.

Comment: Dead @Vlad Mihalcea, thanks for your helping, i follows your instruction, regret it don't resolve error. Here is new updated error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39630113/Picture/DBUpdate.png