# Spring-boot don't work with database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

UPDATE: Oook, first of all, thank you very much. I did not know that user is a reserved keyword in Postgres. I changed the name to CustomUser but now the problem is another, the app works but I noticed that it created an identical CustomUser table called custom_user because it does not use the existing table?

I'm new to Springboot and I do not understand where I am wrong.
This is my model:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomUser")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1813429767195246919L;

    @Id
    @Column(name ="ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "[users_seq]")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "[users_seq]", sequenceName = "[users_seq]", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "AGE", nullable = false)
    private Integer age;

    @Column(name = "SALARY", nullable = false)
    private Integer salary;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
    }

}
```

This is dao interface:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByName(String name);

}
```

This is service and serviceImpl:

```
public interface UserService {

    User findById(Long id);

    List<User> findByName(String name);

    void saveUser(User user);

    void updateUser(User user);

    void deleteUserById(Long id);

    void deleteAllUsers();

    List<User> findAllUsers();

}


@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public User findById(Long id) {
        return userDao.findOne(id);
    }

    public List<User> findByName(String name) {
        return userDao.findByName(name);
    }

    public void saveUser(User user) {
        userDao.save(user);
    }

    public void updateUser(User user){
        saveUser(user);
    }

    public void deleteUserById(Long id){
        userDao.delete(id);
    }

    public void deleteAllUsers(){
        userDao.deleteAll();
    }

    public List<User> findAllUsers(){
        return (List<User>) userDao.findAll();
    }

}
```

This is rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestApiController {
    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestApiController.class);

    @Autowired
    UserService userService; 

    // -------------------Retrieve All Users -----------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> listAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<CustomErrorType>(new CustomErrorType("Users not found"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // -------------------Retrieve Single User -----------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        logger.info("Fetching User with id {}", id);
        User user = userService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            logger.error("User with id {} not found.", id);
            return new ResponseEntity<CustomErrorType>(new CustomErrorType("User with id " + id + " not found"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // -------------------Create a User -----------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody User user, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        logger.info("Creating User : {}", user);

        logger.error("Unable to create. A User with name {} already exist", user.getName());
        userService.saveUser(user);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/api/user/{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    // ------------------- Update a User -----------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {
        logger.info("Updating User with id {}", id);

        User currentUser = userService.findById(id);

        if (currentUser == null) {
            logger.error("Unable to update. User with id {} not found.", id);
            return new ResponseEntity<CustomErrorType>(new CustomErrorType("Unable to upate. User with id " + id + " not found."),
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        currentUser.setName(user.getName());
        currentUser.setAge(user.getAge());
        currentUser.setSalary(user.getSalary());

        userService.updateUser(currentUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // ------------------- Delete a User -----------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        logger.info("Fetching & Deleting User with id {}", id);

        User user = userService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            logger.error("Unable to delete. User with id {} not found.", id);
            // ResponseEntity<CustomErrorType> provare con questo!s
            return new ResponseEntity<CustomErrorType>(new CustomErrorType("Unable to delete. User with id " + id + " not found."),
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        userService.deleteUserById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    // ------------------- Delete All Users -------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteAllUsers() {
        logger.info("Deleting All Users");

        userService.deleteAllUsers();
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

The database (postgresql) consists of a single User table (ID, AGE, NAME, SALARY) when I try to test services using Postman I get this error:

```
2017-05-03 15:20:04.229 ERROR 4921 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column user0_.id does not exist
  Posizione: 8
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc4.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc4.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc4.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc4.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc4.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:305) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc4.jar:9.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:329) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.springboot.example.service.UserServiceImpl.findAllUsers(UserServiceImpl.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.springboot.example.api.RestApiController.listAllUsers(RestApiController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

I hope in your help, thank you very much to everyone.

Comment: ERROR: column user0_.id does not exist

Comment: I guess you can find your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168267/dont-get-all-users-object-in-web-application-spring-mvc-jpa-postgresql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't get all users object in web application spring mvc + jpa + postgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168267/dont-get-all-users-object-in-web-application-spring-mvc-jpa-postgresql)

Comment: Can you update the Model with the new one? It's still the old model

Comment: I've updated the template, but I do not understand why a table is created that is identical to the one already present but called customer_user

Answer (score 0):

Check your table user has id column in database. If not create that and try again. This error basically means the database table and entity is not in sync with respect to columns. Check the column names and types.