# Why is my Python code not inserting data into PostgreSQL database from a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, database, postgresql

I'm trying desing and implement database model in python from a json file but my python code seems like is not inserting data into table and i'm not sure where is the problem in my code

```
import json
import psycopg2


class Policy:
    def __init__(self, type, name, rule_exists):
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.rule_exists = rule_exists


# load json data from the file
with open("demo_data.json", 'r') as file:
    policy_data = json.load(file)
    first_level = policy_data["uniconfig-topology:configuration"]
    second_level = first_level["Cisco-IOS-XR-infra-policymgr-cfg:policy-manager"]
    third_level = second_level["policy-maps"]
    forth_level = third_level["policy-map"]

table_of_policies = []
for item in forth_level:
    if "policy-map" in item:
    # forth_level = item
        type = forth_level['type']
        name = forth_level['name']
        rule_exists = 'policy-map-rule' in forth_level
        policy_map = Policy(type, name, rule_exists)
        table_of_policies.append(policy_map)
    #print(forth_level)


conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="postgres",
    user="postgres",
    password="postgres",
    port="5432"
)


cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS policy_map")
cursor.execute('''create table policy_map
( type VARCHAR(255),
  name VARCHAR(255),
  rule_exists BOOLEAN)
''')

for policy_map in table_of_policies:
    insert_data = "INSERT INTO policy_map (type, name, rule_exists) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(insert_data, (policy_map.type,
                   policy_map.name, policy_map.rule_exists))


conn.commit()
```

I tried several different approach for dict in json file to be sure im on right level of dict but it never append any data to my list. Would like to know whats wrong with my code

Comment: Please post "demo_data.json" sample data

Comment: So the problem is that `table_of_policies` always remain empty?
Does this ever return true?  `"policy-map" in item`

Comment: Could you explain me what you mean by exact level of dict in json? You mean printed items are:

"type"
"name"
"policy-map-rule"
...
like this?

Comment: printed items are all lines of code under dict "policy-map"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type` is a built-in python function that returns the type of a variable. Overwriting it might cause your code to work unexpectedly.

You can check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) , avoid using build-in function names for variables.

Regarding table column naming you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160240/using-type-as-database-column-name).

Apart from these you're looping over `forth_level` but not using the item:

```
type = forth_level['type']
name = forth_level['name']
```

I would expect this code to continue like:

```
    if "policy-map" in item:
    type = item['type']
    name = item['name']
    rule_exists = 'policy-map-rule' in item
    policy_map = Policy(type, name, rule_exists)
    table_of_policies.append(policy_map)
```

But without seeing the JSON I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: That's not the problem even if i replace variable named type its still not adding any data

Comment: I have added another possible problem with your code but without seeing the actual file you're using this is just intuition, as the previous version would end up returning duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents of file `demo_data.json` into a string variable, i.e. `json_text = file.read()` and then pass `json_text` as a single parameter to this query (in variable `the_insert_query`):

```sql
with t as
(
 select j ->> 'name' as "name",
        j ->> 'type' as "type",
        j -> 'policy-map-rule' is not null as rule_exists
 from json_array_elements
 (
  %s::json -> 'uniconfig-topology:configuration'
           -> 'Cisco-IOS-XR-infra-policymgr-cfg:policy-manager'
           -> 'policy-maps'
           -> 'policy-map'
 ) as j
)
insert into policy_map("name", "type", rule_exists) 
select "name", "type", rule_exists from t;
```

`cursor.execute(the_insert_query, (json_text,))`

PostgreSQL would handle the whole case quickly and easily. No `class Policy`, `table_of_policies` or a loop over it are needed at all.