# How to make the 'public' schema default in a Scala Play project that uses PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, scala, playframework

I am not sure if my issue connecting to the Scala Play 2.5.x Framework or to PostgreSQL so I am going to describe my setup.

I am using the Play 2.5.6 with Scala and PostgreSQL 9.5.4-2 from the [BigSQL Sandboxes](http://www.bigsql.org/postgresql/sandboxes.jsp). I use the Play Framework default evolution package to manage the DB versions.

I created a new database in BigSQL Sandbox's PGSQL and PGSQL created a default schema called public. I use this schema for development.

I would like to create a table with the following script (`1.sql` in DB evolution config):

```
# Initialize the database

# --- !Ups

CREATE TABLE user (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

# --- !Downs

DROP TABLE user;
```

Besides that I would like to read the table with a code like this:

```
val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id, name, email FROM public.user WHERE id=" + id.toString)
```

I got an error if I would like to execute any of the mentioned code or even if I use the `CREATE TABLE...` code in pgadmin. The issue is with the `user` table name. If I prefix it with `public` (i.e. `public.user`) everything works fine.

My questions are:

1. Is it normal to prefix the table name with the schema name every time? It seems to odd to me.
2. How can I make the `public` schema a default option so I do not have to qualify the table name? (e.g. `CREATE TABLE user (...);` will not throw an error)

I tried the following:

1. I set the `search_path` for my user: `ALTER USER my_user SET search_path to public;`
2. I set the `search_path` for my database: `ALTER database "my_database" SET search_path TO my_schema;`
3. `search_path` correctly shows this: `"$user",public`

I got the following errors:

1. In Play: `p.a.d.e.DefaultEvolutionsApi - ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"`
2. In pgadmin:

   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"

   LINE 1: CREATE TABLE user (

   ********** Error **********

   ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"

   SQL state: 42601

   Character: 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the default schema. `user` is a reserved word.

You need to use double quotes to be able to create such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

But I **strongly** recommend not doing that. Find a different name that does not require a quoted identifier.

Comment: That was the solution, thank you! I feel that the error message was not really helpful in this case. By the way, I made a short research to see why I had not found this on Google. I should have searched with the phase "create table user". That way I could found your other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256124/cannot-create-a-database-table-named-user-in-postgresql :) I went with the "user_account" name.