# Hibernate Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I really need help I searched in all the questions I found on stackoverflow and nothing works. I have never used hibernate before and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my repository: https://github.com/ionutincau/test_db

I get this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java" "-javaagent:E:\Applications\IntelliJ\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=50372:E:\Applications\IntelliJ\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\out\production\test_db;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\classmate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ionut\IdeaProjects\test_db\lib\hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.2.9.Final.jar" Main
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:50 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:51 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:51 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists User
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:52 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@3a12c404] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table User (userId integer not null, userName varchar(255), primary key (userId)) type=MyISAM
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:52 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@59b38691] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2497)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2455)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Apr 03, 2017 9:05:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@487db668'
Hibernate: insert into User (userName, userId) values (?, ?)
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'test.user' doesn't exist
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Apr 03, 2017 9:05:52 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1434)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3003)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3503)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.user' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Paste whole stack trace... Where is output of `System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");` Paste relevant code rather than whole project.

Comment: According to the stack trace, the error is in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `type=MyISAM` at line 1

Comment: Your error is "Table 'test.user' doesn't exist"

Comment: The table it doen't exist, it should be created by hibernate. What's the point of using hibernate if I need to create the tables in database.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

in your CFG file please change the hibernate dialect

```
<!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

Comment: Also make sure that the table you are creating doesn't use the db reserved words like `group`, `order`, `limit`, etc.

Comment: Why is that dialect needed? What if you had a dialect like org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect? That's what a project I'm working on is using, and it doesn't throw the executing DDL error except on some machines. But I want to know why

Comment: In my case it was a duplicate table name (copy&paste of explicit table naming)

Comment: @neaGaze lifesaver. I was using 'snapshot' as a table name. Unfortunately MySQL logs aren't quite kind enough to point that out.

Comment: @neaGaze thank you so much.... i was using the word group...

Answer (score 108):

I have got this error when trying to create JPA entity with the name "User" (in Postgres) that is reserved.
So the way it is resolved is to change the table name by @Table annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {..}
```

Or change the table name manually.

Comment: It solved my issue. Even using @Table(name="`user`") didn't solved so i have to change my table name to users and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks so much @KirillCh! Postgres really doesn´t support a user table, whereas MySQL and local H2 do... See also [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256124/cannot-create-a-database-table-named-user-in-postgresql).

Comment: Oh man, I spend hours digging around a similar problem, I have been trying to create a table with name `order` and Hibernate threw the same error … and the only way to get rid of this is to pluralize it by appending (s) to order to make it `orders` … and gladly, it went through!

Comment: Also I have found that if choose other schema then “public” you can successfully create “user” table in it.

Comment: This issue occurred to me when I am trying to create leave table, but when I change the table name as leaving it works...

Comment: I had an Entity called "Order"... I wish I had a brain, "order" is a SQL reserved word....

Answer (score 27):

Adding this configuration in **application.properties** file to fixed this issue easily.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

Comment: This one worked for me.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Most of the other answers involve overriding the generated table name to not conflict with a database keyword, but this let's you avoid having to override the table name in case you don't want the table name to be different.

Comment: what does it do?

Answer (score 12):

I got this same error when i was trying to make a table with name "admin".
Then I used @Table annotation and gave table a different name like 
@Table(name = "admins"). I think some words are reserved (like :- keywords in java) and you can not use them.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "admins")
public class Admin extends TrackedEntity {

}
```

Comment: I agree with you I have the same problem after checking I found that i used a reserved postgres word as column name !

Answer (score 4):

Dialects are removed in recent SQL so use

```
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect"/>
```

Comment: This answer is currently being discussed as a possible case of plagiarism on Stack Overflow meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385693/duplicate-answer-flag-rejected

Comment: I meant to use this for recent MySQL. For recent sql we need to specify version in value of dialect. as I am not allowed to comment for above discussion i add here

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to do here is correct the hibernate dialect version like @JavaLearner has explained. Then you have make sure that all the versions of hibernate dependencies you are using are upto date. Typically you would need: database driver like `mysql-connector-java`, hibernate dependency: `hibernate-core` and hibernate entity manager: `hibernate-entitymanager`. Lastly don't forget to check that the database tables you are using are not the reserved words like `order`, `group`, `limit`, etc. It might save you a lot of headache.

Answer (score 2):

Try knowing the version of MySQL you're using, so as to configure your dialect in the application.properties.

if you're using MySQL5. Try this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

if you're using MySQL8. Try this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using an old version of hibernate. You can download the latest version, 5.2, from [here](http://hibernate.org/orm/).

Answer (score 1):

you have to be careful because reseved words are not only for table names, also you have to check column names, my mistake was that one of my columns was named "user". If you are using PostgreSQL the correct dialect is: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`

change `update` to `create`, and run it

after run safely again change `create` to `update` so again all tables will not create and you can use your previous data

Answer (score 1):

Another sneaky issue related to this is naming your columns with `-` instead of `_`.

Something like this will trigger an error at the moment your tables are getting created.

```
@Column(name="verification-token")
```

Answer (score 0):

Might help someone:
In my case it was just as @Kirill Ch said but my table name was called "Order". After I changed it to the "Orders" and changed my hibernate dialect to `spring.jpa.com.human.HibernateConn.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` everything worked as a charm.
If nothing above works for you I suggest to check the list of the all reserved keywords for your DB. Here is the one for MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html.

Answer (score 0):

If non of the answers here works for you, chances are, you are:

1. modifying column constraint but `references the wrong type`, so make sure the type of foreign key is align with the type of the other table's primary key;
2. `useing DB reserved keyword as column name`, just google your db's reserved keyword, and change the column name;

You may find the exact cause, if you scroll to the middle of your stack trace. In my case, it was a `reserved keyword`, and had to reload the editor to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I Just deleted @Table for the Entity Post. Then It works.Only @Entity annotation is there.