# Error executing DDL "alter table score add constraint foreign key (enrollment_id) references enrollment (id)" via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, spring, jpa, foreign-keys

I have an Enrollment class which has list of scores. I am trying to make a reference to the Score class but getting the following:

> Error executing DDL "alter table score add constraint ... foreign key
> (enrollment_id) references enrollment (id)" via JDBC Statement Caused
> by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to open the referenced table
> 'enrollment'

After running the application, the Score table is created in the database, but the Enrollment table is missing and enrollment_id column of the Score is not a foreign key.

**How can I solve this problem?** I have tried to annotated with @Cache and to ignore the double creation of the table but it was not successfull. I am using MySQL.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "enrollment")
public class Enrollment {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    public Student student;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
    public Date date;

    @Column(name = "rank", nullable = false)
    public int rank;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "specialty_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Specialty specialty;
    
    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "files", columnDefinition = "BLOB", nullable = false)
    private byte[] files;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enrollment", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Score> scores;
    
    @Column(name = "state", length = 50, nullable = false)
    public String state;
   
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "score")
public class Score {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "score_forming_object_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ScoreFormingObject scoreFormingObject;
    
    @Column(name = "score", nullable = false)
    private double score;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "enrollment_id")
    private Enrollment enrollment;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64316793/14644191 @Rajib Garai's answer worked for me. I have added spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true to application.properties and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect

adding these 2 to my application.properties solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Enrollment entity class is in the same or in a sub-directory of the application class.

Comment: It is in a sub-directory of the application class. There is also another entitites which are located in the same directory as the Enrollment class for which tables are created in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had been struggling with the same problems later on it works for me when change the table name which was a reserved word in MySQL DB, So make sure when you create a table in mysql db it shouldn't be a **reserved** word.