# Hibernate error when executing JDBC statements - unexpected token 'UNIQUE'

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, mariadb

I searched around and the [only similar StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191294/hibernate-error-executing-ddl-via-jdbc-statement) doesn't address what I'm looking for.

I have defined an auxillary database object in Hibernate like so:

```
<database-object>
    <create>ALTER TABLE project ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE `unique_id` (`userId`);</create>
    <drop></drop>
</database-object>
```

Upon setting up my database and running against passing tests, I get this error thrown:

```
01:56:04.337> WARN   ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl:27 GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "ALTER TABLE project ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE `unique_id` (`userId`);" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "ALTER TABLE project ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE `unique_id` (`userId`);" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:442)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:406)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:164)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:728)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
        at com.ekotrope.server.jdo.BaseJdoTestClass.startServices(BaseJdoTestClass.java:221)
        at com.ekotrope.server.jdo.BaseJdoTestClass.beforeClass(BaseJdoTestClass.java:112)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: UNIQUE
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.execute(NewProxyStatement.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: UNIQUE
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.checkIsNonCoreReservedIdentifier(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.checkIsSchemaObjectName(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readNewSchemaObjectName(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readNewDependentSchemaObjectName(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlterTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlter(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        ... 35 more
```

This is incredibly confusing because executing the above statement within my database (MariaDB) is perfectly valid, yet JDBC doesn't recognize a perfectly fine statement.

Comment: I think the name of the constrain should be *before* the UNIQUE statement? Like `ALTER TABLE table 
ADD CONSTRAINT name UNIQUE (id);`

Comment: Which Hibernate dialect are you using? ([What is the MariaDB dialect class name for Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37066024/12567365))

Comment: @Jelmen After changing it, the error changes to Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token:

Comment: @andrewJames we are using org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB102Dialect with a10.2 MariaDB