# Postgres syntax error for reference

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to create a table with the following query using the pg npm module (v7):

```
CREATE TABLE subscriptions(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    stripe_id VARCHAR(40) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    user INTEGER REFERENCES users,
    plan VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    start DATE NOT NULL,
    end DATE DEFAULT NULL
  );
```

This seems to match the docs but it is throwing an error:

```
 error: syntax error at or near "user"
```

The users table has a serial primary key for id, anyone know why this isn't working?

Edit: here's the docs for reference - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK

I'm using postgresql version 9.4.

Comment: @AvantikaSaini The users table does exist, it has a column for "id" rather than "user", but I understood from the docs that this is OK - see the third example in the docs section referenced above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22256124/330315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*user* is a reserved keyword in postgresql. You may use any other column name in its place

Refer the postgresql documentation for the complete list of keywords - [Key Words List](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

According to it, *end* is also reserved. So the last line of your code will generate an error

Comment: Thanks, that's solved it and looks like "end" is also a reserved keyword.